# Two inboxes for diffrent users in buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I want to have separate inboxes for users, all users are divided in two categories according to their profile fields. now suppose if a user from category1 posts a private message, it should go to inbox1, and if a user from category2 posts a private message, it should go to inbox2.
I am using wordpress 3.9.1
Buddypress 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this with BuddyPress, as things stand. The entire Private Messages component is built around a model of a user only having one set of message. You're best to find another plugin to build your feature on rather than try to hack BuddyPress like this.